# How do I use with-out-str with collections?

Tags: clojure

I can use `with-out-str` to get the string value from `(doc func)`.

```
=> (with-out-str (doc first))
"-------------------------\nclojure.core/first\n([coll])\n  Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its\n    argument. If coll is nil, returns nil.\n"
```

However, if I try to do the same thing with a collection of functions, I can return only the empty string for each:

```
=> (map #(with-out-str (doc %)) [first rest])
("" "")
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately `doc` is a macro, and as such it is not a first class citizen in clojure because you cannot use it as a higher order function.

```
user> (doc doc)
-------------------------
clojure.repl/doc
([name])
Macro
  Prints documentation for a var or special form given its name
```

what you are seeing is the output of looking up the documentation for `%` twice.

```
user> (doc %)
nil

user> (with-out-str (doc %))
""
```

because the call to doc has finished running during macro-expansion-time, before the call to map runs (at run-time). However you can get the doc string directly from the metadata on the `var` containing the functions

```
user> (map #(:doc (meta (resolve %))) '[first rest])
("Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its\n    argument. If coll is nil, returns nil." 
 "Returns a possibly empty seq of the items after the first. Calls seq on its\n  argument.")
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks for your additional edit with an alternative. Very clear.